# Check if parameter is already chosen in console

Tags: c#, parameters, cmd

I'm writing a flesch index calculator and I want to be able to start my program with a console command and the .exe itself. I want to read in .txt files in the console with the command `fleschIndexCalc.exe -f "path of the file"` and then be able to select the calculation formula either for an english text with the parameter `-e` or a german text with `-g`.

When I start it with the console command: I type in the parameters by myself.

When I start it with the .exe: The program asks for the language and I just have to write `g` or`e` and press `enter`.

Now my question: how can I tell my program while starting it with the console that I already chose the language so it doesn't ask me for it again like I started it with the .exe?

Here's what I got:

*(If you need more code from my FleschScore.cs ask for it :) )*

```
namespace Flesch_Reading_Ease
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string[] parameters = new string[] { "-f", "-g", "-e" };


            Console.WriteLine("Flesch Reading Ease");
            Console.WriteLine("");


            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("error!");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("no file found!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("press any key...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
               //------- WHAT TO WRITE HERE? -------
            }

            fileName = args[0];

            FleschScore fs = new FleschScore(fileName);
            fs.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

My method to choose the language looks like this:

```
private void SelectLanguage()
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("choose language:");
                Console.WriteLine("- german(g)");
                Console.WriteLine("- english(e)");

                string lang = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (lang.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "D":
                        _selectedLanguage = Language.German;
                        break;

                    case "E":
                        _selectedLanguage = Language.English;
                        break;

                    default:
                        _selectedLanguage = Language.Undefined;
                        Console.WriteLine("wrong input. Enter viable letter.");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;
                }
            } while (_selectedLanguage == Language.Undefined);
        }
```

Comment: If you start it with the *.exe your args.Length == 2 if you start it from console your args.Length > 2 if i got you right

Comment: I can't see where your program asks for the language option.

Comment: Good point @Steve... how you get filepath if you start with exe?

Comment: I edited my question. Look up there.

Answer (score 4):

You basically loop through all the arguments and keep track of what's already entered. Then after that you check if you have all the info you need and pass everything as parameters to whatever method/class needs it.

```
bool isGerman = false;
bool isEnglish = false;
bool nextEntryIsFileName = false;
string filename = null;

foreach (string arg in args)
{
    switch (arg)
    {
        case "-e":
            isEnglish = true;
            nextEntryIsFileName = false;
            break;
        case "-g":
            isGerman = true;
            nextEntryIsFileName = false;
            break;
        case "-f":
            nextEntryIsFileName = true;
            break;
        default:
            if (nextEntryIsFileName)
            {
                filename = arg;
                nextEntryIsFileName = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}

if (!(isEnglish ^ isGerman))
{
    // Select language
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
{
    // Ask for filename
}

var language = ...

FleschScore fs = new FleschScore(language, fileName);
fs.Run();
```

Comment: It's an exclusive or. It checks if one of the two booleans is true but not both. So if somebody passed both `-e` _and_ `-g` it will also ask to choose  a language as well as when neither of those is passed.